# TypeScript function type assignment

Tags: typescript

Consider the following

```
interface ITest {
    someMethod(a: any): void;
}
const someImplementation = (a) => { return Promise.resolve(); }
const anotherImplementation = (a, b) => { return Promise.resolve(); }

//No error emitted when assigning (a: any) => Promise<void> to (a: any): void
let test1: ITest = { someMethod: someImplementation }; 

// No error emitted when assinging () => Promise<void> to (a: any): void
let test2: ITest = { someMethod: () => someImplementation(1) };

//No error emitted when assigning (a: any) => Promise<void> to (a: any): void
let test3: ITest = { someMethod: (a) => someImplementation(1) };

//Error emitted when assigning (a: any, b: any) => Promise<void> to (a: any): void
//ERROR: Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void'.
let test4: ITest = { someMethod: (a, b) => someImplementation(1) };

//DIFFERENT error emitted when assigning (a: any, b: any) => Promise<void> to (a: any): void
//ERROR: Type '(a: any, b: any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(a: any) => void'.
let test5: ITest = { someMethod: anotherImplementation };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=58#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4BQyxyWA9gLYQCyEYAFmQCYAUcAXMnCAJ4CUnAG5lgTANwEAvgQRkQOUpQioKABwA2EKuDhhgc5AF5kbPkYB8+ZFDoBXKCGQAFKJWBYIAOhvl1giCx8YsjSsvK43GQM0CoaWhA6egbGbAA0yABGZoaWeNZ2Ds6uFO5ePmR+AUEhBAQA9HUAcmTI0K5QrSVgkEzIAO70CVxYWMAA5iCgYyYcXLzZli5uHgA8wqKWYC1snNz8QiJMBJq4kDgAjJwY2LjGeeRUtAzMnA-KapraYLr6jpLBtQayGarSg7U6wG6EF6AyGcBGUymJgWRWWEDWh0221mewEyHWRxOyDOYAATFdMAo7opHnRGExOIELDT3nEvj85CxzmZ-oCmi02mQOlpIT1+oNHPDRhMkTs5vxmUsSqsCViZrt5gdRMc6MSbgBmCk3IxWN5PemMuAot6xT4Jb5JEBcnkSep1ACiYKFEKhMIlw2lkxA0zle3SGQ1CpyqOV6NVxOxkbxBLd7oASmmAPJpzjoHiqFAAciVpQxG0LyHcyBAUQD4xAcAymgTxPzRYJhc8OtONwALEaqaalOaXjNw9alLb4olfs6Qq6GgARVAAMRX6fdjXQoPBIt94rhCJlwfV8vDScVxVL8a2p9xWqODXTWZzyDzBeQhdDvHP8pRJZVTEKyrGsIiPBsmxQW8wDbT9vyjSwOy7IkSQAVgHW4h1pZ4GTmKJBigKd2UdecgA)

Why do the `test1`, `test2`, and `test3` assignments not produce errors about `void to Promist<void>` assignment while the `test4` assignment does?
Also, why would the `test4` and `test5` assignments give different errors?
Is there any implicit assertion going on for `void --> Promise<void>` ?

Comment: If the definition is a void return type then it doesn't matter what value is actually returned, whether it's a promise or not, the caller isn't going to use it. But the number of _arguments_ matters because the caller is only going to be providing one.

Comment: It's because `(a,b) => ... ` requires 2 arguments, while callers of `ITest.someMethod` only need to provide 1.

Answer (score 1):

The number of arguments matter. For the first three tests, the arguments are accepted. Even for empty arguments, if your TS is not that strict it will not complain. It is still valid javascript because an empty argument is undefined, and undefined is considered any.

test4: someMethod expects a return void, but the function you're passing in returns a promise, fix test4 by making `someMethod(a:any) : Promise<void>`

test5: same issue as test4, but also paramater needs to match the type someMethod. fix test4 by making `someMethod(a:any, b?:any) : Promise<void>`

General fix:

```
interface ITest {
    someMethod(a: any, b?: any): Promise<void> | void;
}
```

Comment: How come 1,2,and 3 void worked?

Comment: @3m3sd1 because the playground TS did not include that strict rule. This is still bad practice and when someone use that function in the future, they may run into issues if they don't await. But since its void, most can argue you don't need to await because you're not expecting a value.